# Is this signal periodic?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am wondering if this signal is periodic. I find that it's not periodic but I don't know if I'm not applying a trig identity to it correctly. Is this signal periodic and if not, why?

$\cos(3\pi t)+1$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's periodic. The period is $\frac{2}{3}$; you can check this by writing
$$
f(t) = \cos(3 \pi t) + 1
$$
and simplifying
\begin{align}
f(t + \frac{2}{3})
&= \cos (3 \pi (t + \frac{2}{3}) + 1 \\
&= \cos (3 \pi t + 3\pi\frac{2}{3}) + 1 \\
&= \cos (3 \pi t + 2\pi) + 1 \\
&= \cos (3 \pi t) + 1 \\
&= f(t).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a better perspective on solving future problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Just observe that if $P=\frac{2}{3}$, then

$$\cos\left[3\pi\left(t+P\right)\right]+1=\cos \left(3\pi t+ 3\pi P\right)+1=\cos \left(3\pi t+ 2\pi \right)+1=\cos \left(3\pi t\right)+1$$

Answer (score 0):

It **is** periodic. The definition of a periodic function is that there is a $T$ (called the period) such that $f(t+T) = f(t)$ for all $t$.

If for example we take $T= 2/3$ we get:

$$f(t+T) = \cos(3\pi (t + {2\over 3})) + 1 = \cos(3\pi t + 2\pi) + 1 = \cos(3\pi t) + 1 = f(t)$$